# trustd process v high CPU usage and slooow boot up - OSX 10.13.6

Tags: startup, mac-pro, cpu

My machine used to fly through booting up but since last week it's very sluggish and once I finally log in, three instances of trustd are operating at a very high capacity for 5 minutes or so. After that everything is fine and runs smoothly and quietly.

I can't recall of anything I did that caused the sudden change.

I have tried deleting and resetting the default keychain 
Repairing disk permissions using the terminal. 
First aid on the startup disk using disk utility 
Booting in recovery mode and using first aid on startup disk using disk utility (this made the problem significantly worse. It would take 2/3 minutes to boot before, now 5+)
Deleting valid.sqlite3 file from library/keychains/crls
Removing nsurlsessiond (scraping the barrel here)

Is there a way to see the log of what trustd is doing during startup (and more importantly what it’s having problems with ) that's making it run so hot?

Mac Pro early 2008
10.13.6 (running on unsupported hardware)
22GB RAM
2x 2.8 GHz intel xeon

[image: Activity Monitor Screenshot]

[image: trustd Open Files And Ports]

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but multiple instances of trustd are not in themselves indicators of an issue. The high CPU of course probably is:\ I currently see 5 instances, pretty much 'doing nothing'. It's hard to compare to another Mac Pro 3,1, as trustd didn't exist in El Capitan [or at least it isn't running on my El Cap 3,1 right now & I avoided the Sierras like the plague, didn't update the newer Macs until Mojave]

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for the reply. High Sierra has been fine for me until this but strangely, since posting this (and doing nothing else to try and fix the issue) the problem seems to have corrected itself. It's now running quicker than ever. Boots quickly and no noisy fans or CPU strain. I can only assume that one of the things I did may have worked?